# Jquery confusion with $this

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a way I can show only the button to the box I'm hovering over without using the addclass() property and toggling the visibility. Is there a way to do something like `$(this).('.list_remove').fadeIn("200");` what is the correct way to go about this?

http://jsfiddle.net/HjFPR/7/

### Jquery

```
 (function(){

       $('.list_remove').hide();

      $(".boxes").hover(
      function () {
        $('.list_remove').fadeIn("200");
      },
      function () {
         $('.list_remove').fadeOut("200");
      }
    );

    })();​
```

### HTML

```
<div class="boxes"> 
<input type="button" class="list_remove" value="remove"> </div>
<div class="boxes"> 
    <input type="button" class="list_remove" value="remove">
    </div>​
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HjFPR/11/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a context to search so `$('.list_remove', this).fadeIn("200");` will fade in `.list_remove` descendents of the `.boxes`

```
$(".boxes").hover(
      function () {
        $('.list_remove', this).fadeIn("200");
      },
      function () {
         $('.list_remove', this).fadeOut("200");
      }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by specifying a context for jQuery to find the `list-remove` button in.

```
$('.list_remove', this).fadeIn("200");
$('.list_remove', this).fadeOut("200");
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HjFPR/8/)